# Accessing the user object in a base controller in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, base-class

I have a base controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Auth;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
  use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (!empty($user))
    {
      $uid = $user->id;
      DB::table("users")
        ->where("id", $uid)
        ->update(array(
          'last_time_page_accessed' => time(),
        ));
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, even if I am logged in, it doesn't reach the $uid = $user->id part, because the $user object is always empty.

This is how I call it from the main controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Redirect;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Files;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ChatController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }

}
```

What am i missing? Why can't it access it?

**UPDATE**

I tried switching these, and it also didn't work:

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
    parent::__construct();
  }
```

Comment: `Auth::user()` it will work if your route is protected by `auth()` and  it is base controller it means so many controller which is not protceted by `auth()` it will not work

Comment: The user is not available at the point where the controller is constructed. For what you're trying to do specifically you should use middleware

Answer (score 1):

As apokryfos pointed out, the authenticated user is not yet available when the controller is constructed, so `auth()->user()` will always be `null`.

What you're trying to do is a perfect use case for [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware).

You can use something like this. If you want this code to run for every route, you may register your Middleware as global Middleware for every web route.

```
<?php   

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class StoreLastTimeUserAccessedPage
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
       if ($user = Auth::user()) {
           $user->update([
               'last_time_page_accessed' => time()
           ]);
       }

       return $next($request);
    }
}
```